# Redux - Props not received if deeply nested

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As part of my store, I have the following structure:

```
dataTables: {
        "myTable": {
            loading: false,
            queryParams: {
                searchParams: {},
                filterParams: {},
                sortParam: {},
                skip: null,
                limit: null
            },
            searchTerm: "",
            filter: {},
            data: []
        }
    }
```

and I map this state to the component like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {return {
    dataTable: state.dataTables["myTable"]
}};
```

and I get the props of `data` like this:

```
nextProps.dataTable.data
```

If `data` changes in the store, my component does not receive the updated prop. However, if i change the `mapStateToProps` to the following I receive the updated props:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {return {
    dataTable: state.dataTables["myTable"],
    dataTableData: state.dataTables["myTable"].data
}};
...
nextProps.dataTableData
```

Is this reason I don't receive the props in the first case because `data` is deeply nested inside the `dataTables` state onbject and Redux doesn't detect it?

Comment: Redux doesn't care if your data is nested. It may be that your component uses PureRenderMixin and you are mutating the state. If you provided a fiddle it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Could it be because I am using Object.assign in my reducer?

Comment: It depends on how you are using it. I doubt anyone will be able to help you until you share a small fiddle with what you are trying to do.